# How to use JSON Object itself instead of file path in ConfigurationBuilder?

Tags: c#, json, kubernetes, configurationmanager

I am gettin the json file stored as ConfigMap in K8s cluster. So I do not have the path as required in ConfigurationBuilder class in C#. Is there a way to build configuration from JSON object itself rather than the filepath ?

Comment: You can use [ConfigurationBuilder.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method which accepts configurationsource. You can use [JsonStreamConfigurationSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json.jsonstreamconfigurationsource?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class to load your JSON and pass it to the add method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to get the JSON string from the source,  you can call [ConfigurationBuild.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method by passing it an object of [JsonStreamConfigurationSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json.jsonstreamconfigurationsource?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class.

Following is the sample code.

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

// GetConfigJson method should get the JSON string from the source.
// I am leaving the implementation of that method up to you.
string jsonData = GetConfigJson();
    
// Load the JSON into MemoryStream
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
    
// Create an object of JsonStreamConfigurationSource class.
var configSource = new JsonStreamConfigurationSource();

// Assign stream to it.
configSource.Stream = stream;

// Call Add method of builder by passing the configSource object.
builder.Add(configSource);
```

You can also call [AddJsonStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method on builder by passing the stream to it..

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

// GetConfigJson method should get the JSON string from the source.
// I am leaving the implementation of that method up to you.
string jsonData = GetConfigJson();
    
// Load the JSON into MemoryStream
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));

// Call AddJsonStream method of builder by passing the stream object.
builder.AddJsonStream(stream);
```

I hope this will help resolve you issue.